# How to prompt a user while the OAuth modal is already open in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, oauth, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm trying to handle the [account-exists-with-different-credential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login#handling-account-exists-with-different-credential-errors) error as part of the `firebase` authentication process.  My end goal is to enable the "One account per email address" and link the accounts with the same email addresses using `linkWithCredential`.

Let's say the user has already registered with email/password using `some@gmail.com`, which is in the `firebase` database. When the user tries to login with the Google OAuth using the same email, `some@email.com`, I want to prompt the user to enter the password for the first email/password account so that the user is verified and the two accounts be linked.

The problem is [Expo's Google](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/) or Facebook OAuth opens up a slide-in modal for the OAuth authentication and I'm not sure how to prompt the user for the password while the modal is open. When I `Navigation.navigate()` to another screen while the modal is open, the modal inevitably closes.  React Native's `Alert` doesn't have an input feature, either.

Following is how I'm handling the error:

```js
if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use' || error.code === 'auth/credential-already-in-use' || error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
    const pendingCred = error.credential
    const email = error.email
    firebase
        .auth()
        .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
        .then(methods => {
            if (methods[0] === 'password') {
                 // somehow prompt the user for password
                const password = promptUserForPassword()
                firebase
                    .auth()
                    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .then(user => {
                        return user.linkWithCredential(pendingCred)
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        goToApp();
                    })
            }
        })
    return;
}
```